# How to write this loop prettier?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've just read this topic [highlight search keywords on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930533/highlight-search-keywords-on-hover) and actually I use pretty the same structure, but it looks awful. So can you give me an advice, how to write this loop prettier in one php file, I mean php and html at the same time?

```
<table class="result">
    <?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $cQuote =  highlightWords(htmlspecialchars($row['cQuotes']), $search_result);
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php h($row['cArabic']); ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php echo $cQuote; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;"><?php h($row['vAuthor']); ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;"><?php h($row['vReference']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If there is more of your app try a php framework! Something that allows you to separate the html from php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would keep the HTML section for printing out values only, not doing database connections, calling functions, and so on. Something like this:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $row['cquote_hi'] = highlightWords(htmlspecialchars($row['cQuotes']), $search_result);
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>

<table class="result">
    <?php foreach ( $rows as $row ) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php h($row['cArabic']); ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php echo $row['cquote_hi']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;"><?php h($row['vAuthor']); ?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;"><?php h($row['vReference']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If your server setup allows it, you can echo variables with short tags: `<?=$row['cquote_hi']?>`

I don't know what the h() function is doing but you could perhaps call it for each variable in the original while loop, then just echo the variables.

Comment: I'm much happier with the concept of keeping the database stuff separate from the output. Our web app doesn't do this, and it's a bloody nightmare now when we want to refactor it.

BUT, don't use short_tags. EVER. You might save a little bit of typing, but the clarity of using the long version is much better (and works no matter what your server configuration is).

Comment: Stephen: short tags FTW. There's a reason every templating language uses some form of them.

Answer (score -1):

This would be my way:

```
<?

echo '<table class="result">';

while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $cQuote =  highlightWords(htmlspecialchars($row['cQuotes']), $search_result);

    echo '
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;">'.h($row["cArabic"]).'</td>
        <td style="font-size:16px;">'.$cQuote.'</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;">'.h($row["vAuthor"]).'</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;">'.h($row["vReference"]).'</td>
    </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

All php...